How to do horizontal scroll navigation of columns of text?
I'm a bit new to the game. I'm really stuck and I would love some guidance if you have like 5 minutes.
I think the screenshot are clear enough to see what i'm talking about, but I would like to do some sort of navigation by sliding and snapping three layers of texts on mobile ( from md screen and beyond, it is the regular "on top of each other" layout) horizontally.
I work with laravel 10 + filamentphp v3 + tailwindCSS (with its default config theme from the doc).
Here is the view without interaction in its default state where #surface is in its active state ; the other two, #shallow and #deep are in their inactive state.
<div class="flex justify-center items-center mb-8 min-h-96">
            <h1 class="text-4xl font-sans font-bold text-amber-500 w-full m-8">{{ $fiche->titre }}</h1>
        </div>


        <div id="section" class="flex flex-row md:flex-col h-full truncate mt-auto max-md:flex-grow ">
            @if ($fiche->text_surface)
                <div id="surface" class="md:w-full text-wrap w-full min-w-2 w-0.5">
                    <div class="p-4 bg-blue-100 w-full h-full md:columns-2  pb-8">
                        <p class="mx-8 max-md:hidden">{{ $fiche->text_surface }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif

            <div id="shallow" class=" md:w-full text-wrap">
                @if ($fiche->text_shallow)
                        <div class="p-4 bg-blue-200 w-full h-full md:columns-2  pb-8">
                            <p class=" mx-8 mb-8 ">{{ $fiche->text_shallow }}</p>
                        </div>
                @else
                    <div class="p-4 bg-blue-200 w-full h-full"></div>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div id="deep" class="min-w-2 w-0.5   md:w-full h-auto text-wrap">
                @if ($fiche->text_deep)
                        <div class="p-4 bg-blue-300 w-full h-full md:columns-2  pb-8">
                            <p class="max-md:hidden mx-8 mb-8">{{ $fiche->text_deep }}</p>
                        </div>
                @else
                    <div class="p-4 bg-blue-300 w-full h-full"></div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" p-1 bg-blue-500 "></div>
        <div class="p-0.5 bg-amber-400 "></div>

1st, the default layer visible
2nd, How it should be after a slide from right to left, notice that there are another layer to the right
Have you an idea of how to do this ? Is there a (lightweight) JS library or copy/pastable element of some sort to do this?
If not, can you at least tell me how this kind of "navigation" is called so It can ease my further research?
I tried the scroll and snap feature of native tailwind and it works kinda well, but it eliminates the bars on the sides (which are important for my design) and there is a small horizontal scroll bar on the bottom that I don't want...
After, I tried some javacript and manipulating DOM to switch classes wherever its needs, but it somehow breaks a lot of things like texts not reappearing or suddenly having like 3 kilometers of vertical and horizontal scroll...
Thanks a lot.


Can you at least tell me how this kind of "navigation" is called so It can ease my further research?

I believe what you're looking for is similar to a slider or carousel. Search online for "javascript slider carousel".
Here are links to JavaScript carousel libraries: Splide and glide.js.
Build your own slider/carousel tutorials: How to build a simple carousel.
None of these, however, provide exactly what you're looking for. The images you attached show something similar to an "accordian": A sliver/preview of all previous and next items in the carousel.
You could write your own with the following snippet as a starting point. It's vanilla JavaScript that I pulled from multiple projects I worked on in the past. It emulates the UI of the images in your question.
I didn't include the touch gesture code that allows for left and right swiping. This can be added with libraries such as hammer.js at this link or using the native touch events in the HTML DOM. Two controls are used to test the left and right swiping directions.
Snippet sample
The snippet below works by using a spacer variable, assigned to the value of a CSS variable (defined as --spacer). The spacer variable, in pixels, is used to set the width of each .panel item as well as the left position of a .panel item to create the "stacks" on each side of the visible .panel element.
I included a flag useSpacer at the top of the JavaScript. If set to true, the "stacked" spacing effect is rendered. If useSpacer is set to false, the common slider/carousel UI is rendered without a preview of the previous or next elements.
The .panel-container is set to display: grid; and each child .panel element is stacked on top of each other by setting the CSS property: grid-area: 1/1.
A CSS transition is used on the transform to animate changes to the active .panel element.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize);

let panelContainerEl,
  panelElList;

// Units in 'px'
let panelContainerWidth,
  panelWidth;

let numOfPanels,
  spacer,
  useSpacer = true;

function initialize() {
  panelContainerEl = document.querySelector(".panel-container");
  panelContainerWidth = panelContainerEl.getBoundingClientRect().width;

  panelElList = panelContainerEl.querySelectorAll(".panel");

  numOfPanels = panelElList.length;

  if (useSpacer) {
    // Get CSS variable
    // developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue
    // 'getPropertyValue()' return value: "If not set, returns the empty string."
    spacer = getComputedStyle(panelContainerEl).getPropertyValue('--spacer');
    spacer = spacer === '' || Number.isNaN(spacer) ? 0 : parseInt(spacer, 10);

    panelWidth = panelContainerWidth - ((numOfPanels - 1) * spacer);

    const panelWidthWithUnits = `${panelWidth}px`;

    panelElList.forEach(panelEl => panelEl.style.width = panelWidthWithUnits);

    // Initialize panel display. Set to the first panel
    // (at index '0') in 'panelElList'.
    selectPanel(panelElList[0], 0, false);
  } else {
    panelElList[0].classList.add("panel-in-view");
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(".controls .ctrl")
    .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", controlClickHandler));

  //panelElList.forEach(panelEl => swipeDetect(panelEl, swipeHandler));
}

/* --------------- Display panel -----------------------------------
 */

function displayPanel(dirIndex) {
  const currentPanelEl = panelContainerEl.querySelector(".panel-in-view");

  // Find the index of the panel element within the panel element list
  const currentIndex = [].slice.call(panelElList).indexOf(currentPanelEl);

  const targetIndex = currentIndex + dirIndex;

  if (targetIndex < 0) {
    document.querySelector("#ctrl-message").textContent = "Currently at START of panels";
    return;
  } else if (targetIndex > numOfPanels - 1) {
    document.querySelector("#ctrl-message").textContent = "Currently at END of panels";
    return;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#ctrl-message").textContent = "";
  }

  const animate = true;

  selectPanel(currentPanelEl, targetIndex, animate);
}

function selectPanel(currentPanelEl, targetIndex, animate) {
  if (!currentPanelEl) {
    return;
  }

  const currentIndex = [].slice.call(panelElList).indexOf(currentPanelEl);

  const targetPanelEl = panelElList[targetIndex];

  repositionPanels(currentIndex, targetIndex);

  if (useSpacer) {
    setSpacers(targetIndex);
  }

  if (animate === false) {
    repositionPanels(currentIndex, targetIndex, panelElList);
    currentPanelEl.classList.remove("panel-in-view");
    targetPanelEl.classList.add("panel-in-view");
    return;
  }

  // -------- Set up and trigger transition for the CURRENT panel

  const transitionEndHandlerCur = function() {
    this.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionEndHandlerCur);
    this.classList.remove('is-moving');
  };

  currentPanelEl.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEndHandlerCur);

  // Trigger the transform transition
  currentPanelEl.classList.add('is-moving');
  currentPanelEl.classList.remove('panel-in-view');


  // -------- Set up and trigger transition for the TARGET panel

  const transitionEndHandlerTar = function() {
    this.classList.remove('is-moving');
    this.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionEndHandlerTar);
  };

  targetPanelEl.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionEndHandlerTar);

  // Add the "selected" class to the selected index element
  targetPanelEl.classList.add('is-moving', 'panel-in-view');
}

function repositionPanels(currentIndex, targetIndex) {
  // Reposition list items that have a lower index position to the "left"
  if (currentIndex < targetIndex) {
    // Add left position class
    for (let n = 0; n < targetIndex; n++) {
      panelElList[n].classList.add('translated-left');
    }
  } else {
    // Remove left position class
    for (let n = targetIndex; n < panelElList.length; n++) {
      panelElList[n].classList.remove('translated-left');
    }
  }
}

function setSpacers(targetIndex) {
  panelElList.forEach((panelEl, index) => {
    if (index < targetIndex) {
      panelEl.style.transform = `translateX(calc(-${panelWidth}px + ${(spacer * (index + 1))}px))`;
      panelEl.style.zIndex = numOfPanels - index;
    } else if (index > targetIndex) {
      panelEl.style.transform = `translateX(calc(${panelWidth}px - ${(spacer * (index - 1) * -1)}px))`;
      panelEl.style.zIndex = numOfPanels + index;
    } else if (index === targetIndex) {
      panelEl.style.transform = `translateX(${(spacer * index)}px)`;
      panelEl.style.zIndex = numOfPanels;
    }
  });
}

/* --------------- Scroll controls -----------------------------------
 */

function controlClickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const dirIndex = this.getAttribute("data-dir") === "get-from-right" ? 1 : -1;
  displayPanel(dirIndex);
}
.panel-container {
  --panel-lr-padding: 1rem;
  --spacer: 8;
  /* Units in 'px' */
  display: grid;
  height: fit-content;
  /* Explicitly add the 'position: relative;' so that '.panel'
        child elements are positioned by its 'left' CSS property. */
  position: relative;
  /* Hide container panels that are translated to the right or left. */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  /* This is required to enable correct setting of panel width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  /* By default each panel is positioned off-screen */
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  padding: var(--panel-lr-padding);
  /* This is required to enable correct setting of panel width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel-in-view {
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* Panel hidden from view to the left */

.translated-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}


/* Panel hidden from view to the right */

.translated-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}


/* The 'is-moving' class is assigned to the DOM element
    that is moving out of the viewport. */

.is-moving {
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.controls {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.controls .ctrl {
  padding: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  user-select: none;
}

#ctrl-message {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

#shallow {
  background-color: rgb(205, 233, 255);
}

#mid {
  background-color: rgb(143, 201, 247);
}

#deep {
  background-color: rgb(81, 139, 184);
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
}

#extra-deep {
  background-color: rgb(51, 95, 129);
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
}
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<div class="main-text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <a class="ctrl" data-dir="get-from-right">Swipe Left</a>
  <a class="ctrl" data-dir="get-from-left">Swipe Right</a>
  <span id="ctrl-message"></span>
</div>
<div class="panel-container">
  <div id="shallow" class="panel">
    <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
      from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="mid" class="panel">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
      here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
      up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
      in section 1.10.32.</p>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="deep" class="panel">
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</p>
    <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
      from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="extra-deep" class="panel">
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</p>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks a lot mate, I'll will look into it.
